# Won't `expression` be susbtituted by an expression in a bash command?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to substitute

```
cargo run --example sync_tun -- --tun tun1 172.217.1.14 80
```

by

```
cargo run --example sync_tun -- --tun tun1 `dig google.com +short` 80
```

shouldn't `dig google.com +short` be substituted by the ip?

Comment: It should, although backticks for command substitution are deprecated - `$(dig google.com +short)` is preferred. If that's not happening, then please update your question with more details.

Comment: Turn on the -vx switches for bash and try your command.  You get the input line and the line that gets executed (after all sorts of substitutions). e.g. bash -vx command,   or set -vx  ...etc.